# In Emacs, how can I have the same buffer open in multiple frames (when using ido/iswitch)?

Tags: emacs, elisp, ido-mode

In emacs, I'd like to open the same buffer in multiple frames. Before I used ido, this was easy: I'd just switch to the buffer in one frame with <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>b</kbd>, then focus a different frame in my window manager, and then open the buffer in that other frame too (with <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>b</kbd> again.) But, now that I use ido for fuzzy completion in <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>b</kbd>, when I try to open the second copy of the buffer, it just sends the focus back to the first frame and frustrates me.

Is there a variable I can set to control this behavior?

Ideally, I'd like <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>b</kbd> <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to not be biased at all by the other buffers that are open (normally, it tries to default to a buffer that is not open in any window.)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It looks like

```
(setq ido-default-buffer-method 'selected-window)
```

is what you need.

Comment: FYI for iswitchb, it's `(setq iswitchb-default-method 'samewindow)`

Comment: This only applies to opening buffers with `C-x b`. For opening files with `C-x C-f`, add this too:
`(setq ido-default-buffer-method 'selected-window)`

Comment: HXCaine: s/ido-default-buffer-method/ido-default-file-method/

Answer (score 1):

I use `C-r` in Ido to search backward through it's list.  The buffer that I want has usually been pushed to the end of the list.  I do tend to use multiple window splits (verticle and horizontal) instead of multiple frames.